# How to make Jenkins Blue Ocean UI display a link to Cucumber Reports?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses the [Cucumber Reports plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-reports). I integrated Jenkins with GitLab.

In GitLab, I can see if a specific commit passed the tests, and clicking on an icon I go to the pipeline that tested it. The Blue Ocean interface is displayed.

The problem is that I can't have a link from the Blue Ocean interface to my Cucumber Reports. I enter the classic interface and then click on the Cucumber reports link in the left column.

My end user is editing the tests and I'd like to spare them the understanding of Jenkins' inconsistent user interfaces.

Is it possible to put a link to the report from the Blue Ocean interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't do it till now. My solution was to print it with a echo command in the last stage of the pipeline:

```
echo "CUCUMBER tests report: ${BUILD_URL}cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html"
```

Blue Ocean automatically makes the URL clickable. Nothing fancy, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40616) a discussion on Jenkins forum on similar topic. Looks like it's possible with HTML Publisher plugin. Copying the relevant info here from the jenkins forum, in case the link is unreachable in future:

> **plugin**: HTML Publisher plugin
>
> **jenkinsfile**: `publishHTML(target:
>   [allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: true,
>   reportDir: 'doc/internal/html', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName:
>   'DOC', reportTitles: ''])`
>
> **blueocean ui**: makes the HTML appear as a link in the artifact list in Blue Ocean

Comment: The problem is a little different, since the build just generates a json file. The plugin that creates the html report. Maybe I can find the html and try to publish it, but I think it stays outside the workspace.

Comment: Publish html does not work because cucumber html reports uses a lot of javascript and the publish html plugin escapes it.